# iPhone App Green Screen Replacement

Tags: iphone, core-animation, core-image

Q: I'm looking to use the iPhone camera to take a photo and then replace the green screen in that photo with another photo.

What's the best way to dive into this? I couldn't find many resources online.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, all that you need to do is loop through the pixel data of the photo taken by the phone, and for each pixel that is not within a certain range of green, copy the pixel into the same location on your background image.

Here is an example I modified from keremic's answer to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics) stackoverflow question.
NOTE: This is untested and just intended to give you an idea of a technique that will work

```
//Get data into C array
CGImageRef image = [UIImage CGImage];
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(image);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel_ * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
unsigned char *data = malloc(height * width * bytesPerPixel);
// you will need to copy your background image into resulting_image_data. 
// which I am not showing here
unsigned char *resulting_image_data = malloc(height * width * bytesPerPixel);
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));
CGContextRelease(context);

//loop through each pixel
for(int row = 0; row < height; row++){
  for(int col = 0; col < width*bytesPerPixel; col=col+4){
    red = data[col];
    green = data[col + 1];
    blue = data[col + 2];
    alpha = data[col + 3];
    // if the pixel is within a shade of green
    if(!(green > 250 && red < 10 && blue < 10)){
      //copy them over to the background image
      resulting_image_data[row*col] = red;
      resulting_image_data[row*col+1] = green;
      resulting_image_data[row*col+2] = blue;
      resulting_image_data[row*col+3] = alpha;
    }
  }
}

//covert resulting_image_data into a UIImage
```

Comment: If you do it this way, then you could make some improvements by looking at the surrounding pixels as you loop through it. If most of the surrounding pixels are green but the current one isn't, it's probably really part of the green screen (but due to whatever reason the pixel doesn't look green). Also, using a similar technique you might want to smooth the edges of any detected green screen parts - it'd probably look a little nicer :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at compiling OpenCV for iPhone - not an easy task, but it gives you access to a whole library of really great image processing tools.

I'm using openCV for an app I'm developing at the moment (not all that dissimilar to yours) - for what you're trying to do, openCV would be a great solution, although it requires a bit of learning etc. Once you've got OpenCV working, the actual task of removing green shouldn't be too hard.

**Edit:** This link will be a helpful resource if you do decide to use OpenCV: [Compiling OpenCV for iOS](http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/en)